# The code works, but not sure how to implement it into iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently taking a chemistry class and thought it would be fun to make a program that can calculate the pH of strong/weak acid solutions. The code works in playgrounds and I'd like to eventually implement it into an iOS project. The program takes in 3 parameters: the initial concentration of the acid, the acid's chemical formula, and the equilibrium constant of the acid (if needed). The program begins by taking in the initial concentration of the acid, then it takes in the chemical formula of the acid and determines if the acid is strong or weak. Next, I set up an if statement to calculate the pH according to the strength of the acid. If the acid is weak, an equilibrium constant is needed. Here is what I have so far:

```
import UIKit

func acidConcentration(acidMolarity: Double) -> Double {
    return acidMolarity
}

let initialConcentration = acidConcentration(0.50)

var hydroniumConcentration = 0.00

var pH = 0.00

func determineAcidStrength(acidName: String) -> String {

    var acidStrength = ""

    if acidName=="HBr" || acidName=="HI" || acidName=="HClO4" || acidName=="HCl" || acidName=="HClO3" || acidName=="H2SO4" || acidName=="HNO3" {
        acidStrength = "strong"
    } else {
        acidStrength = "weak"
    }

    return acidStrength

}

let strength = determineAcidStrength("HBr")

if strength == "strong" {

    hydroniumConcentration = initialConcentration

    pH = -log10(hydroniumConcentration)

    print(String(format: "%.2f", pH))

} else {

    func equilibriumConstant(ka: Double) -> Double {
        return ka
    }

    let eqConstant = equilibriumConstant

    var weakAcidConcentration = sqrt(eqConstant(1.8e-5) * initialConcentration)

    pH = -log10(weakAcidConcentration)

    print(String(format: "%.2f", pH))

}
```

As I am very new to programming and this is my first attempt at writing any code, I was wondering if there are any ways to clean up what I have or any tips to organize the code better. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have posted is overly complicated for something that can be accomplished in a single function.

The function below accepts 2 arguments, the acidName as a `String`, and the initialConcentration as a `Double` and returns the concentration as a `Double` value.

```
func calculateConcentration(acidName: String, initialConcentration: Double) -> Double {
    var acidIsStrong = false;

    if acidName=="HBr" || acidName=="HI" || acidName=="HClO4" || acidName=="HCl" || acidName=="HClO3" || acidName=="H2SO4" || acidName=="HNO3" {
        acidIsStrong = true;
    }
    if acidIsStrong {
        return -log10(initialConcentration);
    } else {
        return -log10( (1.8e-5) * initialConcentration);
    }
}
```

Here is an example use of the function:

```
//Just pass in your acid name and initial concentration
let concentration = calculateConcentration("HBr", initialConcentration: 0.50);
print(String(format: "%.2f", concentration));
```

Here is a smaller version of the function written a bit more efficiently (it works the same):

```
func calculateConcentration(acidName: String, initialConcentration: Double) -> Double {
    if acidName=="HBr" || acidName=="HI" || acidName=="HClO4" || acidName=="HCl" || acidName=="HClO3" || acidName=="H2SO4" || acidName=="HNO3" {
        return -log10(initialConcentration);
    }
    return -log10( (1.8e-5) * initialConcentration);
}
```

And an even smaller version that isn't very readable:

```
func calculateConcentration(acidName: String, initialConcentration: Double) -> Double {
    return -log10( initialConcentration * ((acidName=="HBr" || acidName=="HI" || acidName=="HClO4" || acidName=="HCl" || acidName=="HClO3" || acidName=="H2SO4" || acidName=="HNO3") ? (1.8e-5) : 1.0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a chemist so, I'm not sure about the formula, but how about this:

```
class Acid: CustomStringConvertible {

    static let strongAcids = [ "HBr", "HI", "HClO4", "HCl", "HClO3", "H2SO4", "HNO3" ]

    var name: String
    var concentration: Double
    var equilibriumConstant: Double?

    var pH: Double {
        get {
            var adjustedConcentration = concentration
            if !Acid.strongAcids.contains(name) {
                guard let ka = equilibriumConstant else {
                    return Double.NaN;
                }
                adjustedConcentration = sqrt(ka * concentration)
            }
            return -log10(adjustedConcentration)
        }
    }

    init(name: String, concentration: Double, equilibriumConstant ka: Double? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.concentration = concentration
        self.equilibriumConstant = ka
    }

    var description: String {
        get {
            if let ka = equilibriumConstant {
                return "\(name) (concentration: \(concentration) / EqK: \(ka) pH: \(String(format: "%.2f", pH)))"

            } else {
                return "\(name) (concentration: \(concentration) / pH: \(String(format: "%.2f", pH)))"
            }
        }
    }
}

let acid = Acid(name: "HBr", concentration: 0.5);
print("\(acid)") // prints "HBr (concentration: 0.5 / pH: 0.30)"
print(String(format: "%.2f", acid.pH)) // prints "0.30"
let weakAcid = Acid(name: "Weak", concentration: 0.2, equilibriumConstant: 1.8e-5)
print("\(weakAcid)") // prints "Weak (concentration: 0.2 / EqK: 1.8e-05 pH: 2.72)"
```

As for creating an app... For a simple app like this, you can probably just create a "Single View Application" with 3 text fields (name, concentration, and constant) and a button the "calculate".  I hope that makes sense.